# when use matplotlib for making graph, how can i select range?

Tags: python-3.x

in case,
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)
y = x**2 + 2
```

usually make graph for plt.plot(x,y)
but i have useless part.
I thought this to make new array and then append.

```
t = np.array([])
for i in range(len(x)):
    if 4 < i and i < 9:
        continue
    t = np.append(t,x[i])

plt.plot(t,y)
```

or
    new_x = np.array([])

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    if 4<i and i<9:
        new_x = np.delete(x,i)
plt.plot(new_x,y)
```

So, i can remove useless parts.
Does anybody know more good idea for working hour? I have huge datas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `plt.xlim(4, 9)` do what you want? That just limits the area displayed, and you can still pass in all of your data.

---

Ok, so if you really need to slice out the interesting part, the following could be a way. Note that it limits the data by the value of x, not by the index, as in your example.

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)
y = x**2 + 2
interesting_indices = np.argwhere(np.logical_and(x > 4, x < 9))

plt.plot(x[interesting_indices], y[interesting_indices])
```

## Further thoughts:

- Always try to use numpy's builtin element-wise operations rather than looping over items in Python itself. After passing the call, numpy calculates and handles data in its C and Fortran based core, which usually results in way better performance.
- When using `np.append`, it always returns a copy of the old array with the size increased by 1, then removing the old array. That's a lot of memory allocation and freeing up again and therefore very unefficient. Performance-wise, it should even be better to use a `list`:

  `a2 = [val for val in x if 4 < val < 9]`
- Remember to also reduce `y` in the same way as you reduce `x`, otherwise plot cannot match the data to each other.

Comment: no, i am finding the way to interval setting when to use plt.plot

Comment: Alright. I edited the answer with an example of how to do that.

Comment: thank you. although the code that i've written was really awful(it's not working. haha), but you were smart.